# CSS :before text doesn't have the same indentation when wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get some text to show after a custom bullet point. The bullet point is shown using the ":before" pseudo-element but when the text wraps I want it to line up with the first line but it lines up with the ":before" content?
[image]

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="row margin-top-15 slide-content">

<div class="col-xs-6">
    <h5 class="bullet-point">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur pretium malesuada sagittis.</h5>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
    <h5 class="bullet-point">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur pretium malesuada sagittis. Pellentesque ac ultricies diam. Morbi semper nulla nisi, quis semper odio sollicitudin sit amet. Fusce vulputate luctus urna, at tincidunt ligula placerat ut. </h5>
</div>
```

and this is my css class

```
.bullet-point:before{
  content: '>';
  color: white;
  background-color: #179fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 55px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bmLmx0e2/1/

Comment: Something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/vabii/rzyhstrg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to give `position: absolute` to the bullet and add a padding-left to the text.

https://jsfiddle.net/yemtbo50/

CSS:

```
.bullet-point {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.bullet-point:before{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

And don't forget to give `position: relative` to the parent :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use `float:left`..

https://jsfiddle.net/xravg01o/

```
.bullet-point:before{
  content: '>';
  color: white;
  background-color: #179fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 55px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will help you.

```
.bullet-point{
  padding-left:60px;
  position:relative;
}

.bullet-point:before{
  content: '>';
  color: white;
  background-color: #179fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 55px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bmLmx0e2/2/